# Clear multiple lines from the python console

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to code a dice game in python. I have to print the number and also the dices, but those have to disappear after a few seconds.

My output (using the python console) looks like this: [First output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uUAd.png)

After three seconds, the outputs looks like this: [Output after 3 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHFfE.png)

I used `end="\r"` and the code line looks like this:

```
print("Your number is:", dice_values_lookup.get(dice_value), dice_forms(dice_value), end="\r")
            time.sleep(3)
            print("                                         ", end="\r")
```

How can I clear not only the last line but the dices as well? Without clearing the whole console.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: Unfortunately no :8

Comment: in some consoles/terminals (at least on Linux) you can `print()` special codes to move cursor in any place (even few lines up) and then you could `print()` lines with spaces to remove previous chars.

Comment: in documentation of [colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama) you can see codes like `ESC [ n A` to move cursor `n`lines up. Maybe it works on all systems if you use `colorama`. You could also try standard module [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses) - maybe it has similar function.